# I'm not sure how to solve these error codes for HTML.

Tags: html

I get error code: 
(Attribute “name” not allowed on element “area” at this point.)

From line 26, column 3 to line 29, column 51

From line 30, column 3 to line 33, column 55

From line 34, column 3 to line 37, column 57

From line 38, column 3 to line 41, column 37

From line 42, column 3 to line 45, column 75

From line 46, column 3 to line 49, column 41

From line 50, column 3 to line 53, column 51

From line 54, column 3 to line 57, column 37

```
                    +
```

(Element “area” is missing required attribute “alt”.)

From line 59, column 3 to line 59, column 43

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--
 Tutorial 2 
 Author: Logan Henson
 Date: 26 Jan 2018
-->
 <meta charset = "utf-8" />
 <script src="modernizr-2.js"></script>
 <title>Australia Map</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>
 <img src="images/australia_logo.jpg" alt="Australia logo" />
</p>

<p> 
 <img src="images/australia_map.jpg" alt="Map of
 Australia" usemap = "#australia_map"/> 
</p>

<p> 
 <map name="australia_map">
    <area name="South Australia" shape="rect" 
        coords="305,368,495,633" 
        href="australia_states.htm#South%20Australia" 
        alt="South Australia" title="South Australia" />
    <area name="Western Australia" shape="rect" 
        coords="17,113,296,569"
        href="australia_states.htm#Western%20Australia" 
        alt="Western Australia" title="Western Australia" />
    <area name="Northern Territories" shape="rect" 
        coords="302,58,459,363" 
        href="australia_states.htm#Northern%20Territory" 
        alt="Northern Territory" title="Northern Territory" />
    <area name="Tasmania" shape="circle" 
        coords="572,686,42" 
        href="australia_states.htm#Tasmania" 
        alt="Tasmania" title="Tasmania" />
    <area name="Australia Capital Territory" shape="circle" 
        coords="628,562,20" 
        href="australia_states.htm#ACT" 
        alt="Australia Capital Territory" title="Australia Capital 
        Territory" />
    <area name="Queensland" shape="poly" 
        coords="467,184,464,360,518,365,512,423,730,436,558,61" 
        href="australia_states.htm#Queensland" 
        alt="Queensland" title="Queensland" />
    <area name="New South Wales" shape="poly" 
        coords="508,428,722,439,652,558,625,532,598,567,500,516" 
        href="australia_states.htm#NSW" 
        alt="New South Wales" title="New South Wales" />
    <area name="Victoria" shape="poly" 
        coords="501,522,497,605,641,614"
        href="australia_states.htm#Victoria" 
        alt="Victoria" title="Victoria" />

    <area shape="default" href="index.htm" /> 
    </map>
    </p>

  </body> 
  </html>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get these errors ?

Comment: I just tested it and I'm getting no errors. It's very unusual to get such errors with HTML. Could it be associated with something else, like a framework you're using?

Comment: The errors seem pretty self explanatory to me, remove the name attribute from the area elements that have one and add an alt attribute to those that don't have one?

Comment: `<area>` does not use or need a closing slash and one has never been specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of HTML5, the [`<area>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area) no longer has the `name` attribute, so you shouldn't be setting it. Historically, it was used solely to support browsers that relied on it for DOM manipulation. In other words, it serves no purpose and makes your code invalid, so just remove it.

The other error is more self-explanatory: all your `<area>` tags should have the `alt` attribute set to something. This one doesn't:

```
    <area shape="default" href="index.htm" />
```

Comment: `<area>` does not use or need a closing slash and one has never been specified.